# Python iterating bug inside nest dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I try to write flatten code for CHECKIO and i got strange result.
When I try to flatten dict inside dict inside dict .

```
def flatten(dic, prefix =""):
    results = {}
    for k in dic:
        prefix = prefix+"/"+k if prefix else k
        print(prefix)
        if isinstance(dic[k], dict):
            results = dict(list(results.items()) + list(flatten(dic[k],prefix).items()))
        else:
            results[prefix] = dic[k]
    return results
print(flatten({"name": {
                        "first": "One",
                        "last": "Drone"},
                    "job": "scout",
                    "recent": {},
                    "additional": {
                        "place": {

                            "zone": "1",
                            "cell": "2"}}}))
```

Its seems like the code jump inside the dict without Iterating with the first item in the dict first (`name`).
When I try to use `keys()` on the main dict I get the internal items to. Anyone know why? from my knowledge it shouldn't happen.

Thanks

Comment: Im not a native english speaker. don't be mean..

Comment: Also do join us in [The English Language chat-room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70232/the-english-language), if you have any problem regarding language. Happy to help you in all ways possible. Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start with `prefix==""`,

```
prefix = prefix+"/"+k if prefix else k
```

only works correctly for the 1st key. On the next iteration, `prefix` is no longer `""` so the function starts "stockpiling" the keys on top of one another.

Use another variable for the combined prefix and never overwrite the value from the argument.

UPDATE: Regarding the order of the entries in the result. Your example `dict` essentially looks like this:

```
{   "name": {
        "first": "One",
        "last": "Drone"},
    "job": "scout",
    "recent": {},
    "additional": {
        "place": {
            "zone": "1",
            "cell": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

So the outermost `flatten` invocation will iterate over the top-level keys - `name`, `job`, `recent` and `additional` - in some undefined order.

Comment: Hey, that's a useful helping tip. Thanks. But I stile got the same bug after the change /=

Comment: Did you replace the references to the combined prefix further in the code? That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Yep, in the first iteration my code pull `recent` when it should pull `name`

Comment: The key order in a Python `dict` is undefined, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.items . Use `OrderedDict` or some supplemental structure if you need some strict order.

Comment: I know....but it should not enter inside the nest dict if I loop with the item on the first level. to access `recent` it has to loop trough name first.

Comment: `recent` is on the same level as `name` in your example... I'll update the answer.

Comment: `pprint` on the console helps in such cases - it shows every top-level key-value pair on a separate line. `ipython` console uses it by default.